# Tensorflow 2: GradientTape returns None

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have the following code, written in tf.keras with Tensorflow 2. Basically; I need the cross entropy term's gradient with respect to the variable  `self.temperature`. `dce1_dx` correctly calculates the derivative. But on the other hand, when I wrap the same cross entropy calculation into a tf.keras.Model object, the second gradient calculation, `dce2_dx` returns `None`. What is the difference between these two tf.GradientTape calculations? I am experienced in TF1 but newly switching to TF2 and eager execution, so I am stuck at that point.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

logits = np.random.uniform(low=-10.0, high=10.0, size=(10000, 5))
labels = np.random.randint(low=0, high=5, size=(10000, ))
logits_tf = tf.keras.Input(name="logits_tf", shape=(logits.shape[1]), dtype=tf.float32)
labels_tf = tf.keras.Input(name="labels_tf", shape=(), dtype=tf.int32)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((logits, labels))
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size=logits.shape[0])
for lgts, idx in dataset:
   temperature = tf.Variable(name="temperature", dtype=tf.float32, initial_value=tf.constant(2.0),
                               trainable=True)
   scaled_logits = logits_tf / temperature
   ce_loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
   ce_loss = ce_loss(labels_tf, scaled_logits)
   model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[logits_tf, labels_tf], outputs=[ce_loss], name="calibration_model")
   with tf.GradientTape() as tape0:
       tape0.watch(temperature)
       scaled_lgts = tf.cast(lgts, tf.float32) / temperature
       ce = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
       ce = ce(idx, scaled_lgts)
   dce1_dx = tape0.gradient(ce, temperature)

   with tf.GradientTape() as tape1:
       # Compute the derivative: d{CrossEntropy}/d{Temperature}
       tape1.watch(temperature)
       ce2 = model([lgts, idx])
   # !!!Returns None!!!
   dce2_dx = tape1.gradient(ce2, temperature)
```

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation? Did you check that `ce_loss` ends up with the value you expect it to have?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, ce_loss seems to carry the expected value. I tried to follow the documentation for tf.GradientTape.

Comment: What are `logitsTf` and `labelsTf`? A [minmal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help.

Comment: @Lescurel I have edited the code snipped; it is now copy & paste reproducible.

Comment: I can't reproduce with tf 2,4. I get `dce2_dx = <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-1.5056767>`

Comment: Incredibly weird. I have version 2.3 and I get dce1_dx properly but dce2_dx is None.